# "undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass" appearing after form input with sanitization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitization, form-for, strip-tags

I'm using a `form_tag` in my Rails 3 app for a form not bound to any model. I understand (although please correct me if I'm wrong) that this helper doesn't have the same sanitisation benefits as the model-bound `form_for` helper, so I'm manually sanitising all input into the form.

Here's my controller (just the basics):

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

class MyController < ApplicationController

   localVariable = params[:my_form_param].to_s

   localVariable = strip_tags(localVariable)

   localVariable = sanitize(localVariable)

end
```

The problem occurs when characters such as Cyrillic letters, Scandinavian characters, and so on, are included in the form field. The following message is returned:

```
undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass
```

I've narrowed it down to the `strip_tags` and `sanitize` methods, but I really need to use them to remove bad input. I've tried shifting the to_s method as well to each of the methods (e.g. `strip_tags (localVariable.to_s)` ) but with no luck - the only way I'm sure the form will work is by commenting out these two lines altogether (which, as I say, is something I don't want to do).

Anyone got any thoughts on this? Is there an alternative approach I could use, bearing in mind I'm not using a model here, so using `form_for` might be going a bit overboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this problem, using both Tamer Shlash's advice and through hacking the code a bit.

The order of the code also seems to be important - do a `strip_tags`, then a `sanitize`, then finally add the `to_str` method, as follows:

```
    include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

    class MyController < ApplicationController

       localVariable = params[:my_form_param].to_s

       localVariable = strip_tags(localVariable)

       localVariable = sanitize(localVariable)

       localVariable = localVariable.to_str

    end
```

The error message no longer appears.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the same but that was reported to rails [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1739).

It should be solved by using the `to_str` method instead of `to_s`, i.e:

```
localVariable = params[:my_form_param].to_str
```